# Adding two columns from tables having same structure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as follows :-

```
           Table 1                      Table 2 
         date     value             date     value 
         1120101   v11              1120102   v21
         1120202   v12              1120303   v22  
         1120203   v13              1120104   v23
```

what is the sql query to get following output

```
        date         value 
       1120101       (v11)
       1120102       (v12+v21)
       1120103       (v13+v22)
       1120104       ( v23)
```

I tired following query but failed to get desired output

```
select table1.date,
       table2.date,
       table1.delta+table2.delta as delta 
from table1,
     table2   
where table1.date=table2.date;
```

thanks in advance .

Comment: Your dates in Table 1 and Table 2 are different... What is the rule that says that `1120202` in table 1 and `1120102` in table 2 should be joined up in the output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT date, SUM(value)
FROM
(
    SELECT date, value FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date, value FROM table2
) a
GROUP BY date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*data is different but idea is the same*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b10d2/2)

Answer (score 2):

play with subqueries and union:

```
SELECT
    c.date,
    COALESCE(a.value, 0) + COALESCE(z.value,0)
FROM (
    SELECT
        date
    FROM table1
    UNION
        SELECT date
    FROM table2
) AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 a
    ON a.date = c.date
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 z
    ON z.date = c.date
```